# Select any sibling in CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-selectors

I'm making an AngularJS component and I want to select ANY sibling of a tag, no matter if they're `div`s or `span`s or `p`. I am looking for something that is CSS native and like `div:siblings {color: red;}`. Can't find it anywhere. Do you know if it exists?

Comment: in css you can select any **next** siblings via the selector : `div ~ *` for your case here .  see for more about selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Adding this to show that there is no previous sibling selector: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS sibling selectors `~` and `+` only select siblings *after* a particular element. So those won't be useful if you want to select also the preceding siblings.

But one thing you can do is the following combination of CSS rules:

```css
.container>* {
  color: red;
}
.xxx {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some Text some Text</p>
  <div>Some Text some Text</div>
  <p>Some Text some Text</p>
  <p>Some Text some Text</p>
  <p class="xxx">This one has the class mentioned in the text</p>
  <p>Some Text some Text</p>
  <span>Some Text some Text</span>
</div>
```

The first rule selects all *direct* children of the container (and sets their text color), the second one selects the one sibling which has that class (`xxx`) and **resets** its color to the default. This should also be possible with other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the sibling combinator like this

```css
p.target ~ * {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>First paragraph</p>
<p class="target">Second paragraph</p>
<p>Third paragraph</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph</p>
```

You'll need to target the first instance of the element to apply the style to all siblings as shown in the example above.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator